# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_props$checkWeather.err')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, weather-api

Given this code

```
import React from 'react';

const Result = props => {

    const {err, city} = props.checkWeather
     return (
         <div>Pogoda dla: {city} </div>
    );
}

export default Result;
```

I see this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_props$checkWeather.err')

If I delete the line `const{err,city} = props.checWeather`... it works, but not how I want to...

Comment: how are you passing `checkWeather` to the `Result` component?

Comment: `checkWeather` was not provided. You probably forgot to add it wherever you're using this component, e.g. `<Result checkWeather={ ... } />`.

Comment: I do it in class App:

render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <Form 
        text={this.state.value}
        change={this.handleInputChange}
        submit={this.handleCitySubmit}
        />
        <Result checkWeather={this.state}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

Comment: Yes I do. render(){ return( <div className="App"> <Form text={this.state.value} change={this.handleInputChange} submit={this.handleCitySubmit} /> <Result checkWeather={this.state}/> </div> ); } } export default App;